# How can I add a date to an object in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

am sending an put request based on these files.

Venue.ts file

```
export class Venue {
    id: number;
    venueName: string;
    cityName: string;
    emailContact: string;
    fighter1: string;
    fighter2: string;
    dateOfFight: Date;
    active: boolean;
}
```

My Angular Component files:

create-venue.component.html

```
<h3>Create Event</h3>
<div [hidden]="submitted" style="width: 400px;">
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Venue Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="venueName" required [(ngModel)]="venue.venueName" name="venueName">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">City Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cityName" required [(ngModel)]="venue.cityName" name="cityName">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Email Contact</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailContact" required [(ngModel)]="venue.emailContact" name="emailContact">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Fighter 1 Contact</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fighter1" required [(ngModel)]="venue.fighter1" name="fighter1">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Fighter 2 Contact</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fighter2" required [(ngModel)]="venue.fighter2" name="fighter2">
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Choose a time for your Event:</label>
      <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="dateOfFight" min="2021-01-01T00:00" max="2023-06-14T00:00" required [(ngModel)]="venue.dateOfFight" name="dateOfFight">
    </div> 

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div [hidden]="!submitted">
  <h4>You submitted successfully!</h4>
  <!-- <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="newVenue()">Add</button> -->
</div>
```

create-venue.component.ts

```
import { VenueService } from '../venue.service';
import { Venue} from '../venue';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-venue',
  templateUrl: './create-venue.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-venue.component.css']
})
export class CreateVenueComponent implements OnInit {

  venue: Venue = new Venue();

  submitted = false;

  constructor(private venueService: VenueService,
    private router: Router) {}


  ngOnInit() {
  }

  newVenue(): void {
    this.submitted = false;
    this.venue = new Venue();
  }

  save() {
    this.venueService.createVenue(this.venue)
    .subscribe(data => console.log(data), error => console.log(error));
    this.venue = new Venue();
    this.gotoList();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.save();    
  }

  gotoList() {
    this.router.navigate(['/venues']);
  }
}
```

My current sent data in chrome:
[image: my sent data]

I am quite new to javascript and angular, maybe this was answered before but I have no idea how to get the input data into the Venue object...

Edit:
This is my header tab:
[image: header tab]I

Comment: Note that AngularJS refers to version 1 which is quite different than versions 2+ which just use [tag:angular] tag

Comment: @charlietfl This looks like v2+

Comment: @TrevorKropp yes but title and tagging were different until I changed them

Comment: You are previewing the response. What is in the request?

Comment: @TrevorKropp the last image is my request.  I just need to add the date I pick from the  datetime-local type to my request so it does not show up as null but as what I select.

Comment: Try printing out the object when you submit (`console.log(this.venue);`) and see what you get.

Comment: The last image is what my application send to my REST endpoint. Doubt it will be any different since it represents the same data. Edit: It is the same.

Comment: @staynless, when you have problem with request payload, you need to check in 'Headers' tab for request payload but not in 'Preview' tab as it's meant for parsed response. so get the log of request payload.

Comment: Updated with picture, yes indeed there is no date as expected since I can not find a way to add it to my request object...

Comment: I this I got it, I can't actually send a Date... I need to put a String in the JSON for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

using a string instead of Date type for the dateOfFight property will let you post to the backend without issue.

You can then generate the date with `new Date(datestring)` on your server if needed. On the front end you can look into [date pipes](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) which will help you format the string accordingly.

You also seem to not be capturing any values in your date input. Notice venue.dateOfFight is not even there. Perhaps try logging out your data before posting

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string instead of date type `dateOfFight: string;`, and before saving, trasform it into a date format with [Moment js](https://momentjs.com/).

```
 moment(Date.now()).format('YYYY-MM-DD').toString()
```